# Create and save list to an excel file

Tags: python

I want to put some values (`nu` variable values in the loop) in a `list` and then `export` the list to an `excel`. Does anyone have some tips to how I can do this?

[The values I want in a list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4gOL.png)

```
import numpy as np 
import math
from scipy.stats import skew, kurtosis, kurtosistest
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm,t
import pandas as pd

for i in range(0, 3000):

    data = pd.read_excel(r"x.xlsx",skipfooter=i,skiprows=3867-i,usecols="C")
    ret = np.array(data.values)



    from scipy.stats import skew, kurtosis
    X = np.random.randn(10000000)
    print(skew(X))
    print(kurtosis(X, fisher=False))

    # N(x; mu, sig) best fit (finding: mu, stdev)
    mu_norm, sig_norm = norm.fit(ret)
    dx = 0.0001  # resolution
    x = np.arange(-0.1, 0.1, dx)
    pdf = norm.pdf(x, mu_norm, sig_norm)
    print("Integral norm.pdf(x; mu_norm, sig_norm) dx = %.2f" % (np.sum(pdf*dx)))
    print("Sample mean  = %.5f" % mu_norm)
    print("Sample stdev = %.5f" % sig_norm)
    print()

    df = pd.DataFrame(ret)

    # Student t best fit (finding: nu)
    Parm = t.fit(ret)
    nu, mu_t, sig_t = Parm
    pdf2 = t.pdf(x, nu, mu_t, sig_t)
    print("Integral t.pdf(x; mu, sig) dx = %.2f" % (np.sum(pdf2*dx)))
    print("nu = %.2f" % nu)
    print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you want to **put nu values in a list in python** just declare the list outside the for loop:

```
listOfNu=[]
```

Then in this piece of code you can **append to your list the values**:

```
....
print("nu = %.2f" % nu)
listOfNu.append(nu)
print()
...
```

2) Then **to export the list in an excel file** (use dependency `xlwt` by installing it with `sudo easy_install xlwt`):

```
import xlwt
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('nu_example_sheet')

for i,e in enumerate(listOfNu):
    sheet1.write(i,1,e)

name = "nu_example_file.xls"
book.save(name)
book.save(TemporaryFile())
```

[image: Example of the output file with a list of random numbers]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can save the list to excel?

Comment: @jokabaka I updated my answer, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. Saved my day!